# Loop Data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Looking at how to write a script that will show all "storm reports" no matter if there are 2 or 20 returns, possibly looping the data. Data comes from an API JSON response. My current script will only show the amount I have limited the request to.  The example below, if there is only 1 API storm report response, then the script will not show anything the HTML.

```
<script>

window.onload = () => {
const target = document.getElementById('stormreport2');
const aeris = new AerisWeather('[CLIENT_ID]', '[CLIENT_SECRET]');
const request = aeris.api().endpoint('stormreports').action('search').from('-120hour').query('state:sd').limit(2);
request.get().then((result) => {
const report = result.data;
if (report) {
console.log(report);
const html = (`
<div class="alertmessage">
${aeris.utils.dates.format(new Date(report[0].report.timestamp * 1000), 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a')}<br>${report[0].report.type} ${report[0].report.detail.text || ''}${report[0].report.code == `H` ? `"` : ``}${report[0].report.code == `G` ? `MPH` : ``}<br>Location: ${report[0].report.name} (${report[0].place.county} County) <br>${report[0].report.comments || ''}<br><br>
${aeris.utils.dates.format(new Date(report[1].report.timestamp * 1000), 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a')}<br>${report[1].report.type} ${report[1].report.detail.text || ''}${report[1].report.code == `H` ? `"` : ``}${report[1].report.code == `G` ? `MPH` : ``}<br>Location: ${report[1].report.name} (${report[1].place.county} County) <br>${report[1].report.comments || ''}<br><br>
</div>
`);
target.innerHTML = html;
}
});
};

</script>
```

JSON Response Example

```
{
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "response": [
        {
            "id": "64b16a09709b660027c4affb",
            "loc": {
                "long": -103.41,
                "lat": 44.13
            },
            "report": {
                "timestamp": 1689343200,
                "dateTimeISO": "2023-07-14T08:00:00-06:00",
                "code": "R",
                "type": "rain",
                "cat": "rain",
                "name": "4 mi NNE Johnson Siding",
                "detail": {
                    "text": "1.19",
                    "rainIN": 1.19,
                    "rainMM": 30.23
                },
                "reporter": "cocorahs",
                "wfo": "",
                "comments": "24-hour rainfall.",
                "datetime": "2023-07-14T08:00:00-06:00"
            },
            "place": {
                "name": "johnson siding",
                "state": "sd",
                "county": "pennington",
                "country": "us"
            },
            "profile": {
                "tz": "America/Denver"
            },
            "relativeTo": {
                "lat": 44.08471,
                "long": -103.43797,
                "bearing": 24,
                "bearingENG": "NNE",
                "distanceKM": 5.509,
                "distanceMI": 3.423
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "64aed51a709b660027c3ba3d",
            "loc": {
                "long": -103.48,
                "lat": 44.06
            },
            "report": {
                "timestamp": 1689174000,
                "dateTimeISO": "2023-07-12T09:00:00-06:00",
                "code": "R",
                "type": "rain",
                "cat": "rain",
                "name": "1 mi ESE Pactola Resv",
                "detail": {
                    "text": "1.02",
                    "rainIN": 1.02,
                    "rainMM": 25.91
                },
                "reporter": "co-op observer",
                "wfo": "",
                "comments": "24-hour rainfall.",
                "datetime": "2023-07-12T09:00:00-06:00"
            },
            "place": {
                "name": "johnson siding",
                "state": "sd",
                "county": "pennington",
                "country": "us"
            },
            "profile": {
                "tz": "America/Denver"
            },
            "relativeTo": {
                "lat": 44.08471,
                "long": -103.43797,
                "bearing": 231,
                "bearingENG": "SW",
                "distanceKM": 4.339,
                "distanceMI": 2.696
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: [Is that what you want?](https://jsfiddle.net/8ahrju3k/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you Lightning McQueen!